# Finding Avg of following dataset

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Following is the data.

```
select * from  (
    select to_date('20140601','YYYYMMDD') log_date, null weight  from dual
    union
    select to_date('20140601','YYYYMMDD')+1 log_date, 0 weight   from dual
    union
    select to_date('20140601','YYYYMMDD')+2 log_date, 4 weight   from dual
    union
    select to_date('20140601','YYYYMMDD')+3 log_date, 4 weight  from dual
    union
    select to_date('20140601','YYYYMMDD')+4 log_date, null weight from dual
    union
    select to_date('20140601','YYYYMMDD')+5 log_date, 8 weight  from dual);

Log_date   weight  avg_weight
---------------------------------- 
6/1/2014   NULL    0    (0/1) Since no previous data, I consider it as 0
6/2/2014   0       0    ((0+0)/2)
6/3/2014   4       4/3  ((0+0+4)/3)
6/4/2014   4       2    (0+0+4+4)/4
6/5/2014   NULL    2    (0+0+4+4+2)/5   Since it is NULL I want to take previous day avg = 2
6/6/2014   8       3    (0+0+4+4+2+8)/6 =3
```

So the average for the above data should be 3.

How can I achieve this in SQL instead of PLSQL. Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Please [format](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your question such that we can read it.

Comment: What happens when you have two or three `NULL`s in a row?

Comment: if no null records exists before then the average is considered as zero. if exists then average before the 3 row considered as daily value. so that average remains same even we have missing data in between

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just learned how to use recursive CTEs today, really excited! Hope this helps...

```
; WITH RawData (log_Date, Weight) AS (
                select cast('2014-06-01' as SMALLDATETIME)+0, null
    UNION ALL   select cast('2014-06-01' as SMALLDATETIME)+1, 0
    UNION ALL   select cast('2014-06-01' as SMALLDATETIME)+2, 4
    UNION ALL   select cast('2014-06-01' as SMALLDATETIME)+3, 4
    UNION ALL   select cast('2014-06-01' as SMALLDATETIME)+4, null
    UNION ALL   select cast('2014-06-01' as SMALLDATETIME)+5, 8
)
, IndexedData (Id, log_Date, Weight) AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY log_Date)
         , log_Date
         , Weight
    FROM RawData
)
, ResultData (Id, log_Date, Weight, total, avg_weight) AS (
    SELECT    Id
            , log_Date
            , Weight
            , CAST(CASE WHEN Weight IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Weight END AS FLOAT)
            , CAST(CASE WHEN Weight IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Weight END AS FLOAT)
        FROM IndexedData
        WHERE Id = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT    i.Id
            , i.log_Date
            , i.Weight
            , CAST(r.total + CASE WHEN i.Weight IS NULL THEN r.avg_weight ELSE i.Weight END AS FLOAT)
            , CAST(r.total + CASE WHEN i.Weight IS NULL THEN r.avg_weight ELSE i.Weight END AS FLOAT) / i.Id
    FROM ResultData r
    JOIN IndexedData i ON i.Id = r.Id + 1
)
SELECT Log_Date, Weight, avg_weight FROM ResultData
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

This gives the output:

```
Log_Date                Weight      avg_weight
----------------------- ----------- ----------------------
2014-06-01 00:00:00     NULL        0
2014-06-02 00:00:00     0           0
2014-06-03 00:00:00     4           1.33333333333333
2014-06-04 00:00:00     4           2
2014-06-05 00:00:00     NULL        2
2014-06-06 00:00:00     8           3
```

*Note that in my answer, I modified the "Data" section of your question as it didn't compile for me. It's still the same data though, hope it helps.*

**Edit:** By default, MAXRECURSION is set to 100. This means that the query will not work for more than 101 rows of Raw Data. By adding the `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)`, I have removed this limit so that the query works for all input data. However, this can be dangerous if the query isn't tested thoroughly because it might lead to infinite recursion.